# Understanding MCE errors on Linux

Tags: linux, cpu, unix, hardware-failure, error-correction

I got an MCE hardware error on Linux. I used `rasdaemon` to log all errors. Here is what `ras-mc-ctl  --errors` prints me

```
41 2023-01-03 10:50:51 +0100 error: Corrected error, no action required., CPU 2, bank Load Store Unit (bank=0), mcg mcgstatus=0, mci Error_overflow, mcgcap=0x00000117, status=0xd820000000100015, misc=0xd01b0fff00000000, walltime=0x63b3fa7b, cpu=0x00000001, cpuid=0x00800f11, apicid=0x00000002
42 2023-01-03 10:50:51 +0100 error: Corrected error, no action required., CPU 2, bank Load Store Unit (bank=0), mcg mcgstatus=0, mci Error_overflow, mcgcap=0x00000117, status=0xd820000000100015, misc=0xd01b0fff00000000, walltime=0x63b3fa7b, cpu=0x00000007, cpuid=0x00800f11, apicid=0x00000003
43 2023-01-03 10:56:02 +0100 error: Corrected error, no action required., CPU 2, bank Load Store Unit (bank=0), mcg mcgstatus=0, mci Error_overflow, mcgcap=0x00000117, status=0xd820000000100015, misc=0xd01b0fff00000000, walltime=0x63b3fbb2, cpu=0x00000007, cpuid=0x00800f11, apicid=0x00000003
```

And every 5 mins there are more errors like that. I don't know how to read and decode those errors. Also, it's saying `no action required` but my PC is randomly rebooting.
I have AMD Ryzen processor and using Ubuntu latest version.

Worth to mention that I did not change anything in the BIOS, CPU and RAM is not overclocked and RAM pass memtest.

`syslogs`:

```
jakub-comp kernel: [ 7476.357023] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
Jan  3 12:24:14 jakub-comp kernel: [ 7476.357029] [Hardware Error]: Corrected error, no action required.
Jan  3 12:24:14 jakub-comp kernel: [ 7476.357035] [Hardware Error]: CPU:1 (17:1:1) MC0_STATUS[Over|CE|MiscV|-|-|-|SyndV|-|-|-]: 0xd820000000100015
Jan  3 12:24:14 jakub-comp kernel: [ 7476.357049] [Hardware Error]: IPID: 0x000000b000000000, Syndrome: 0x000000003a034102
Jan  3 12:24:14 jakub-comp kernel: [ 7476.357056] [Hardware Error]: Load Store Unit Ext. Error Code: 16, Level 2 TLB parity error.
Jan  3 12:24:14 jakub-comp kernel: [ 7476.357061] [Hardware Error]: cache level: L1, tx: DATA
Jan  3 12:24:14 jakub-comp kernel: [ 7476.357075] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
Jan  3 12:24:14 jakub-comp kernel: [ 7476.357077] [Hardware Error]: Corrected error, no action required.
Jan  3 12:24:14 jakub-comp kernel: [ 7476.357081] [Hardware Error]: CPU:7 (17:1:1) MC0_STATUS[Over|CE|MiscV|-|-|-|SyndV|-|-|-]: 0xd820000000100015
Jan  3 12:24:14 jakub-comp kernel: [ 7476.357110] [Hardware Error]: IPID: 0x000000b000000000, Syndrome: 0x000000003a034b02
Jan  3 12:24:14 jakub-comp kernel: [ 7476.357118] [Hardware Error]: Load Store Unit Ext. Error Code: 16, Level 2 TLB parity error.
Jan  3 12:24:14 jakub-comp kernel: [ 7476.357124] [Hardware Error]: cache level: L1, tx: DATA
```

Comment: I'm getting similar error on Asrock X570D4U and Ryzen 5800X, only my errors says  Corrected error, no action required., CPU 2, bank Unified Memory Controller V2 (bank=10), mcg mcgstatus=0, mci Processor_context_corrupt CECC. It happened only twice in few weeks so far.

Comment: @JánLalinský I got rid off this error and any problems by replacing motherboard and processor.

Comment: I'm getting similar errors once every  few months on a ASUS motherboard (replaced once) and a Ryzen 5800X. Since it appears to be a problem with CPU cache, I presume its always recoverable?